# How to change the list of objects inside the map using streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

Got two maps

```
Map<String, TConfig> configMaps= new HashMap<>();
Map<String, List<Issue>> issuesMap= new HashMap<>();

@Data
public class TConfig {
  private String teamId;
  private String teamName;
}

@Data
public class Issue {
  private String issueId;
  private String teamId;
}
```

Both the maps using `teamId` as the key.

#### Wanted

I would like to set the `teamId` property inside the list of `Issue` objects present in the second map `issuesMap` from the `teamId` present as key in the first map `configsMap`.

#### Tried

I tried it but not failing.

```
configMaps.keySet().stream()
  .forEach(teamId -> issuesMap.values().stream()
       .filter(tid -> teamId.equals(tid))
       .forEach(is-> is.teamId=teamId)
   );
```

#### Questions

1. How do I set it using the streams API instead of  traditional for loops?
2. Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: I don't understand your goal: both maps use a teamId as key. You want to manipulate only the `issuesMap` and set what exactly based on what? Can you add a short example to your question please? (What do both maps contain before and after the searched algorithm?). And maybe you also could provide the code how you would do it in "traditional for loops".

Comment: Well for one, your properties are all private and you're trying to access them directly with `is.teamId=teamId`. Also I'm not fully comprehending the relationships here... you're saying that `teamId` is the key for both maps, correct? If so, shouldn't `teamId` already be set on each of the entries?

Comment: Why isn’t “TConfig” named simply “Team” as its fields seem to describe each team? And more importantly, why not use objects of that class as keys to a single map (`Map< Team , List< Issue > >`) rather than extracting strings as keys? I suspect you are mentally focused on string manipulations rather than using the features of the type system afforded by object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Mapping each team to their issues

You can use objects as keys, as [Basil suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75689397/how-to-change-the-list-of-objects-inside-the-map-using-streams#comment133528456_75689397).

Then `Map<String, TConfig> configMaps= new HashMap<>();` is maybe not needed at all.

```
@Data
public class Team {  // renamed from TConfig
  private String teamId;
  private String teamName;
}

// given
Map<Team, List<Issue>> issuesByTeam = new HashMap<>();
```

Now I see two use-cases to change the values of this map:

1. the issue-list is not mapped correctly to the team, some issues belong to foreign teams
2. the issue-list was somehow distributed to teams, so that the issues inside the list (value) need to be updated with the related team (key)

#### (1) Suppose your issue-list is not yet mapped correctly

That map's values are each a list of issues. However, those `List<Issues>` may contain foreign issues - foreign because not all issues belong to the respective team from respective key. Then you can filter out the foreign issues, to get only team-related ones:

```
for (final Team team : issuesByTeam.keySet()) {  // team must be final to use in lambda later
    List<Issue> unmappedIssues = issuesByTeam.get(team);  // suppose they are not correctly mapped yet

    // filtering
    List<Issue> issuesForTeam = unmappedIssues.stream()
        .filter(issue -> team.equals(issue.getTeamId()))  // only issues matching the team
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    issuesByTeam.put(team, issuesForTeam);
}
```

You could also iterate over each entry using:

```
for (Map.Entry<Team, List<Issue>> entry : issuesForTeam.entrySet()) {
    final Team team = entry.getKey();
    List<Issue> unmappedIssues = entry.getValue();
    // filter like above
    entry.setValue(issuesForTeam);
}
```

#### (2) assign the team from key to each issue in value's list

```
for (Map.Entry<Team, List<Issue>> entry : issuesForTeam.entrySet()) {
    final Team team = entry.getKey();
    List<Issue> unassignedIssues = entry.getValue();
    // assign the team to each issue
    unassignedIssues.forEach(
        issue -> issue.setTeamId(team.getTeamId())
    );
}
```

Here you don't need a stream, `List` implements [`forEach` method of interface Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) directly.

#### See also

Following tutorials from Baeldung may help:

- [Working With Maps Using Streams](https://www.baeldung.com/java-maps-streams)
- [Using the Map.Entry Java Class](https://www.baeldung.com/java-map-entry)